# How do I remove duplicates from two arrays?

Tags: java, arrays

I need to have an algorithm that changes values in one array if it is in the second array.  The result is that the first array should not have any values that are in the second array.

The arrays are of random length (on average ranging from 0 to 15 integers each), and the content of each array is a list of sorted numbers, ranging from 0 to 90.

```
public void clearDuplicates(int[] A, int[] B){
    for(int i = 0; i < A.length; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < B.length; j++)
            if(A[i] == B[j])
                A[i]++;
    }
}
```

My current code does not clear all of the duplicates. On top of that it might be possible it will creat an index out of bounds, or the content can get above 90.

Comment: what do you mean by clear? delete? Why not List?

Comment: `A[i]++;` - Why are you incrementing `A[i]`?

Comment: @almas With clear i mean: replace the duplicate value with a new integer, one that doesnt appear in the other array

Comment: How would you like to handle the case when `A.length + B.length > 90`?

Comment: @maroun i did that because i dont see a way to change the value differently. Because i want it to be a random integer.

Comment: @Gábor that won't happen

Comment: If you have more than 91 integers all in the range 0-90, there *will* be at least one duplicate.  [Pigeonhole Principal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle)

Comment: @don That won't happen

Comment: do you need table A to have unique values only (not duplicates in itself?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although your question is not very clear, this might do the job. Assumptions:

1. The number of integers in A and B is smaller than 90.
2. The array A is not sorted afterwards (use `Arrays.sort()` if you wish to
   fix that).
3. The array A might contain duplicates within itself afterwards.

   ```
   public void clearDuplicates(int[] A, int[] B) {
       // Initialize a set of numbers which are not in B to all numbers 0--90
       final Set<Integer> notInB = new HashSet<>();
       for (int i = 0; i <= 90; i++) {
           notInB.add(i);
       }
       // Create a set of numbers which are in B. Since lookups in hash set are
       // O(1), this will be much more efficient than manually searching over B
       // each time. At the same time, remove elements which are in B from the
       // set of elements not in B.
       final Set<Integer> bSet = new HashSet<>();
       for (final int b : B) {
           bSet.add(b);
           notInB.remove(b);
       }

       // Search and remove duplicates
       for (int i = 0; i < A.length; i++) {
           if (bSet.contains(A[i])) {
               // Try to replace the duplicate by a number not in B
               if (!notInB.isEmpty()) {
                   A[i] = notInB.iterator().next();
                   // Remove the added value from notInB
                   notInB.remove(A[i]);
               }
               // If not possible, return - there is no way to remove the
               // duplicates with the given constraints
               else {
                   return;
               }
           }
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#removeAll%28java.util.Collection%29

Comment: Thx! The use of a set with numbers which aren't used did the trick

Comment: Probably a `BitSet` would be a better fit instead of `Set<Integer>`.

Comment: True, but since performance and efficiency is not an issue here I used `Set` to improve readability of the code.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it just by using int[ ] although it's a bit cumbersome. The only constraint is that there may not be duplicates within B itself.

```
public void clearDuplicates(int[] A, int[] B) {
    //Number of duplicates
    int duplicate = 0;
    //First you need to find the number of duplicates
    for (int i = 0; i < A.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < B.length; j++)
            if (A[i] == B[j]) 
                duplicate++;
    }
    //New A without duplicates
    int[] newA = new int[A.length-duplicate];
    //For indexing elements in the new A
    int notDuplicate = 0;
    //For knowing if it is or isn't a duplicate
    boolean check;
    //Filling the new A (without duplicates)
    for (int i = 0; i < A.length; i++) {
        check = true;
        for (int j = 0; j < B.length; j++) {
            if (A[i] == B[j]) {
                check = false;
                notDuplicate--;//Adjusting the index
            }
        }
        //Put this element in the new array
        if(check)
            newA[notDuplicate] = A[i];

        notDuplicate++;//Adjusting the index
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

public class DuplicateRemove {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] A = { 1, 8, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
    int[] B = { 1, 4 };
    print(clear(A, B));
}

public static int[] clear(int[] A, int[] B) {
    int a = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < A.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < B.length; j++) {
            if (A[i] == B[j]) {
                a++;
                for (int k = i; k < A.length - a; k++) {
                    A[k] = A[k + 1];
                }
            }
        }

    }
    int[] C = new int[A.length - a];
    for (int p = 0; p < C.length; p++)
        C[p] = A[p];
    return C;

}

public static void print(int[] A) {
    for (int i = 0; i < A.length; i++)
        System.out.println("Element: " + A[i]);
}
```

}
Here is an example.. I compiled and its working. For any question just let me know :)

Answer (score -1):

maybe you should try the following code:

```
public void clear (int[] A, int[] B)
{
  for (int i=0; i<A.length;i++)
  {
     for (int j=0; j<B.length; j++)
         if(A[i]==B[j])
         {
           for (int k=i; k<A.length;k++)
           A[k]=A[k+1];
           j=B.length-1; //so that the cycle for will not be executed
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you even try to compile your code and run it? Your brackets make me cry a little.

Comment: I didnt add brackets to the last for cycle because it is intended to execute only one line.

Comment: Your if statement doesn't look like it's closed (but it is, only because you didn't *actually* use one on the for loop). It's completely unclear what you even intended your code to do.

Comment: It gets an element from the first array which is A[i] and compares it with all the elements of B array. As soon as it finds a duplicate it executes the for cycle which intends to delete that element. Hope thats clear now.

Comment: No, it's not. It'd be clearer if you fixed your code.